# Firefox changed it's default search engine --without any update--, is this possible?

Tags: arch-linux, security, firefox

Suddenly the default serach engine of my Firefox browser on ArchLinux is changed. I have no idea how this happend. This morning I worked o the machine and everything seemd okay, now serveral hours later, the search engine is changed without any intervetion (AFAIK). No updates were made.

Please help to detect what happened.

Comment: I don't really think we can answer this. The default search engine is just a setting. Could you have changed it and forgotten? Does anyone else have access to your machine? Could you have added an extension recently? What did the search engine change to? See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1044537

Comment: You can easily change the default setting by pressing Ctrl+Up/Down in the search bar. Maybe you did so by accident?

Comment: Thank you @terdon. I found the issue. Apparently the profile loader found an error inside my profile and loaded the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox profile manager found an issue with my Firefox profile and loaded the default factory settings. If you encounter similar issues, make sure you have loaded **the expected profile**.

Note you can start the Firefox profile manager from terminal with

```
$ firefox --ProfileManager
```